# How to make Visual Studio create a project that use IIS by default

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

For my current daily  job duty I create lots of small Web applications(`Webforms` `asp.net 4.5`).

For development and testing we are required to use local `IIS`.

Is there anyway to make VS creates an empty Web project which uses local IIS by default(from the beginning?

Please note I know how to change  a project to use local `IIS` from `IIS Express` and this is not a the question here.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Use IIS Express for new file-based web sites and projects`?

Comment: No, I will take a look.

Comment: There is no such option in VS 2012 or VS2013

Comment: Sorry, I missed a sub folder. `Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use IIS.....` (VS 2012 Premium edition)

Comment: Still I do not see such option.